# Docusign navigate to a Visualforce page upon signing

Tags: docusignapi

Can we navigate signer who is on a Mobile device (Salesforce 1) to a visualforce page when the document is signed and the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Are you initiating the envelope from SalesForce? The DocuSign web console? Or the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this.  You'll need to use the DocuSign API and more specifically, the **Embedding** functionality which will allow you to sign through a `webview` or an `iFrame` on the mobile device.

With Embedding you can control the redirects URLs based on actions the user takes.  For instance, if the user signs you can navigate to the Visual Force page in question.  Or, if the user declines to sign then you can navigate them to a different page if you'd like.  Same thing for if they hit the X to close the signing window.

To get started with learning DocuSign's APIs check out the DocuSign Developer Center:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center

And for code samples of Embedded Signing in 6 different language stacks see the bottom 3 API Walkthroughs in the API Tools section:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs